# Как найти того, кто «оценит» твой код?

Tags: поддержка, тематика

Я новичок во фронтенде, в частности в верстке. Всевозможные книги, блоги, видеокурсы, скринтасты - это, конечно, хорошо. Но, все же, наибольший профит обучающийся получает именно с помощью практики ( ну в данном случае, когда сам верстаешь какой-то макет, ну или что-то поменьше )...
Но, сверстать что-то это ведь тоже всего лишь полдела. Важно, чтобы это было сделано максимально верно.

В общем, подскажите, пожалуйста, как лучше это осуществить. Чтобы тебя "попинали" за написанный тобою код, написали, как ненужно делать/как сделать лучше, то есть провели своеобразный код ревью.

**Может, есть какой-то ресурс, где меня не пошлют с такой просьбой? )
Интересует именно фронтэнд (на данном этапе - верстка, но в приоритете программирование ).
Идеальным, конечно, вариантом было, если бы уже опытный фронтендер взял меня в "ученики"**

Среди знакомых, к сожалению, таких нет :(
Быть может, среди вас есть, кто готов пойти на это. Обещаю не тупить и не задалбывать )

Comment: Кажется, надо бы ответ принять?

Answer (score 9):

Здесь разрешены вопросы на ревью кода.

Можно задать вопрос с просьбой сделать ревью кода, поставив соответствующую метку [инспекция-кода](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-review) (только сначала ознакомьтесь с [требованиями к таким вопросам](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0/info)).

Можно создать чат (если хватает репутации) и позвать в него желающих тебе помочь.

Покажи хоть что-нибудь, а там видно будет.

Answer (score 2):

Здесь оценят.

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Пишем работающий кусок кода и просим отзывов... Прочитайте там, для начала, правила для создания тем.

Comment: Почему там, а не тут? У нас разрешены вопросы по [tag:code-review].