# Что для пользователя означает перенос вопроса с сайта на мету?

Tags: поддержка, знаки, репутация

Обратил внимание на пользователя [JohnCoffee](//ru.stackoverflow.com/users/29863/johncoffee) и стало интересно, что же происходит в случае переноса вопроса с ненулевым рейтингом с [основного сайта](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/489516/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82-%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4) на [Мету](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2504/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82-%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4). Вычитаются ли баллы за этот вопрос на основном сайте, добавляются ли на Мете, где он может получить за него знаки и т. д.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вроде бы всё очевидно.

1. Полученная за вопрос репутация на основном сайте сохраняется. Сегодня уже 11 число, если бы пересчёт репутации был, то он бы уже произошёл.

   > [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
   >
   > [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
2. На Мете репутации нет, но есть псевдо-репутация, по которой выдаются знаки группы «[Легенда](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/43/legendary)». Не вижу причин обрабатывать перенесённые вопросы как-то иначе, так что псевдо-репутация за этот вопрос наверняка даётся. Точнее может сказать сам автор, выбрав на своей странице этот знак.

   > [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
3. Рейтинг по меткам за вопросы не начисляется, так что пересчитывать как на основном сайте, так и на Мете нечего. Однако вопрос получил положительную оценку, так что он приближает автора к знакам группы «[Сократ](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/89/socratic)»